# TypeError: handel_users_id is not a Function

Tags: reactjs, function, tailwind-css

I am trying to pass call back function from Usercontroller.js component to users.js component. it is **not working**. When I am trying to pass prop I am getting this error:

> TypeError: handel_users_id is not a Function

Here is my code:

## Usercontroller.js

```
const UsersController = () => {
  const [selected_user_id_, set_selected_user_id_] = useState('');

  // function defination work of the function 
  const handel_users_id = (id) => {
    //   set_page_index(2)
    // set_selected_user_id_(id);
    console.log(id, "user id")
  }

  set_selected_user_id_("hello prop")
  return (
    <>
 
      {(selected_user_id_ === '') && <Users handel_users_id={handel_users_id}  selected_user_id_={selected_user_id_} />}
      {(selected_user_id_ !== '') && <RecipeDetail selected_user_id_={selected_user_id_} />}
   
    </>
  )
}
```

Here is my second file name as User.js

## users.js

```
function Users({ handel_users_id }) {
 handle_id = (id) => {
   console.log(handel_users_id,"prop")
   }
  return (
    <>
      <Button layout="link" size="icon" aria-label="Edit" onClick={() => handel_users_id(user.firebase_id)}>
        <EditIcon className="w-5 h-5 mx-3" aria-hidden="true" />
      </Button>
    </>
  )
}
export default Users
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the parameter passed to handle_users_id in the Users component because you have defined the function outside of the component.

```js
function Users() {
 handle_id = (id) => {
   console.log(handel_users_id,"prop")
   }
  return (
    <>
      <Button layout="link" size="icon" aria-label="Edit" onClick={() => handel_users_id(user.firebase_id)}>
        <EditIcon className="w-5 h-5 mx-3" aria-hidden="true" />
      </Button>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: I have improved the code kindly now look at it